# Class declaration and action on class instances

Tags: python

I am following the book "how to think like a computer scientist" to learn python
and am having some problems understanding the classes and object chapter.

An exercise there says to write a function named moveRect that takes a Rectangle and 2 parameters named dx& dy. It should change the location of the rectangle by adding dx to the x co-ordinate of corner and dy to the y co-ordinate of corner.

Now, I am not really sure if the code I have written is correct or not.
So, let me tell you what i was trying to do
and you can tell me whether I was doing it right?

first I created a class Rectangle
then I created an instance of it 
and entered the details such as 
values of co-ordinates x and y
and width and height of the rectangle.

so, this was my code earlier:

```
class Rectangle:
    pass
rect=Rectangle()
rect.x=3.0
rect.y=4.0
rect.width=50
rect.height=120

def moveRect(Rectangle,dx,dy):
    Rectangle.x=Rectangle.x + dx
    Rectangle.y=Rectangle.y + dy

dx=raw_input("enter dx value:")
dy=raw_input("enter dy value:")

moveRect(Rectangle,dx,dy)
```

But when I ran this code it gave me an attribute error
and : class Rectangle has no attribute x

Therefore, I moved the following lines into the moveRect function

```
rect=Rectangle()
rect.x=3.0
rect.y=4.0
rect.width=50
rect.height=120
```

and thus the code became:

```
class Rectangle:
    pass


def moveRect(Rectangle,dx,dy):
    Rectangle.x=Rectangle.x + dx
    Rectangle.y=Rectangle.y + dy
    rect=Rectangle()
    rect.x=3.0
    rect.y=4.0
    rect.width=50
    rect.height=120


dx=raw_input("enter dx value:")
dy=raw_input("enter dy value:")

moveRect(Rectangle,dx,dy)
```

But, this code still gives me an error.
So,what's actually wrong with this code?
At the moment, I feel as if I wrote this code using trial and error,
and changed around the parts when I saw an error. I want to properly understand
how this works.so,please shed some light on this.

The book "how to think like a computer scientist" hasn't introduced init in chapter 12 and therefore I need to do it without using init.

Comment: in your moveRect method, you pass a class instead of passing an object of the type Rectangle. That's why you cannot call Rectangle.x, Rectangle.y.

Comment: so, you mean I should pass rect instead of Rectangle, right??

Comment: exactly! if you wanna use what you did, but the accepted answer is also..a good answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must specify the members and methods you want to access and use in your class declaration. inside the class the Instance you are currently working on is refered to by the name `self` (see the link below!):

```
class Rectangle:
   def __init__(self):
       self.x = 0
       self.y = 0
       self.width = 50
       self.height = 30

   # may I recommend to make the moveRect function
   # a method of Rectangle, like so:
   def move(self, dx, dy):
       self.x += dx
       self.y += dy
```

Then instanciate your class and use the returned object:

```
 r = Rectangle()
 r.x = 5
 r.y = 10
 r.width = 50
 r.height = 10
 r.move(25, 10)
```

hope that helps.

Read: http://www.diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/defining_classes.html

Comment: You mix up class variables and instance variables.

Comment: Honestly, I'm using class variables only in this example (or so I thought). Could you point out, where I mix them up? Thank you.

Comment: @flexy: In your second block you are creating instance variables which mask the class variables. You should use instance variables throughout.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I corrected my response to reflect this.

Answer (score 6):

In your first example, you passed the *class* as an argument instead of the *instance* you created. Because there is no `self.x` in the class `Rectangle`, the error was raised.

You could just put the function in the class:

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def moveRect(self, dx, dy):
        self.x += dx
        self.y += dy

rect = Rectangle(3.0, 4.0, 50, 120)

dx = raw_input("enter dx value:")
dy = raw_input("enter dy value:")
rect.moveRect(float(dx), float(dy))
```

Comment: umm, I didn't understand what you mean.Where should I put self.x?

Comment: @faraz In the [`__init__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) construction. Pretty much, when you create an instance of the class, the `__init__` block will run (it's short for **init**ialise) ;)

Comment: but isn't Rectangle.x or rect.x the same as self.x?
as for the __init__ , they haven't introduced it in the classes and object chapter i.e. chapter 12.

Comment: hmm, i think I understand. I should put in an object/instance as argument instead of class. hmm,got it.

Comment: @faraz yea, it's the same, but my code just kinda cleans it up :p.

Answer (score 4):

Without overly complicating things, all you need to make your code work is to change

```
moveRect(Rectangle,dx,dy)
```

to

```
moveRect(rect, float(dx), float(dy))
```

(You need to make sure to convert each string from `raw_input` into a number. In `moveRect`, you add `Rectangle.x` to `dx`, these two values need to be of the same type or you will get a `TypeError`.)

**Given the knowledge that the [book](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/html/index.html) you're reading expects you to have when completing this [exercise](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/html/thinkpython016.html#toc168), you have completed that problem correctly.**

As others have said, this isn't an approach that you would ever probably use to tackle this. If you carry on reading, you'll see the way to include a function as part of the class definition (as a method); it makes more sense to bundle data and the functions that operate on that data together into a unit.

Comment: hmm, okay I think I got what I was doing wrong. Your explanation was simple and helpful. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Frob instances, not types.

```
moveRect(rect, dx, dy)
```

Comment: I really didnt understand. it says its an image gallery of frobs